# Hosting PHP(Joomla 3) project on Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, joomla

I am trying to host my PHP(Joomla 3) on heroku, I have succeeded to push it on heroku but when I lunched the website I got the following error:

"Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation Error: Could not connect to MySQL."

How can I fix this problem, what is the best solution for that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear on how Heroku works, but this is a standard DB error with Joomla.

This error typically points to your MySQL config not pointing to the correct place. If you just moved your Joomla to Heroku, this could have happened.

Go to the configuration.php file in the root of your project and check the connection settings on **lines 16-19**, to make sure they're pointing to the right place. They'll look like that.

```
public $host = '192.168.1.1';
public $user = 'user';
public $password = 'pass';
public $db = 'db';
```

If you've just pushed the PHP to Heroku, the host is likely still pointing to the site's original location. If you're running your MySQL on a separate remote server, you'll need to change the host string. Otherwise, you'll need to migrate the DB too.

**//EDIT - TEST YOUR MySQL**

It might be worth checking with a standard connection script to see if it throws an error. Create a PHP test file like below and see what PHP errors are thrown:

```
   <?
    $connect=mysql_connect("dbserver","dbuser","dbpassword") or die("Unable to Connect");
    mysql_select_db("dbname") or die("Could not open the db");
    $showtablequery="SHOW TABLES FROM dbname";
    $query_result=mysql_query($showtablequery);
    while($showtablerow = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
    {
    echo $showtablerow[0]." ";
    } 
    ?>
```

This should give you an indication where your MySQL connection is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have already done what you just said but still get the same error!!

Comment: Where is your MySQL db hosted? On the same server or elsewhere?

Comment: Check my edit above to see if you can find out more about the connection error.

Comment: I got a blank page .. nothing in it

Comment: If you got a blank page from that script, this normally indicates your database is empty (i.e. there are no tables)... You might want to check if you've imported your Joomla DB correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `PHPMYADMIN` side and try to repair all tables. It worked for me.